# Animações flash convertidas para HTML5 não ajustam no div

Tags: css, html5-canvas

Converti uma serie de animações flash para HTML5, porem depois da conversão as animações (agora em html5) não ficam ajustadas dentro da DIV.

Antes da conversão estava assim:

```
<video src="caminho/animacao.swf" autoplay controls ></video>
```

Apos a conversão eu -intuitivamente- alterei para:

```
<object class="myObject" type="text/html" data="caminho/animacao.html"></object>
```

onde:

```
.myObject {
              height:450px;
              width:650px;
        }
```

Tenho certeza que o problema é minha inexperiência com css e html, pois tenho mais experiência back-end

edit: [animação html5](http://www.rapidshare.com.cn/Sn2q734)

Comment: O que que não ajusta? A animação estrapola o tamanho da div? A div corta a animação? E qual o código da animação?

Comment: Ficou meio confuso, vc quer alinhar a div.myObject na página, ou alinhas as animações que estão dentro da div.myObject? Se for isso posta o conteúdo completo da animação e da página ok

Comment: A div tem um tamanho fixo na página. E são diversas animações de tamanhos distintos. O que não estou conseguindo e fazer com que essas animações fiquem enquadradas dentro desse div de tamanho fixo. As animações menores que o div ficam desalinhadas e as animações maiores que o div só exibem a parte que cabe no div.

Comment: o path das animações são cadastradas em uma tabela. A animação exibida e selecionada em um menu.

Comment: Dentro da página .html da animação existe uma função que seta as dimensões da animação. Você pode alterar isso ou não?

Comment: acredito que sim, o problema e que são inúmeras animações o  seria muito trabalhoso. gostaria de deixar preparado para que ao enviar a animação para a aplicação, esse ajuste fosse gerado automaticamente.